# C++ IntelliSense does not work with remote-SSH

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed Remote-SSH and C/C++ extensions.
VS client is on my PC (win10) and backend/remote is my linux env (centos 7)
I am able to get/open the code and work perfectly in the terminal (executing any linux command)
For some reason IntelliSense does not work properly on my c++ code.
When I point my mouse over a variable it displays something like class::type but this is the only thing that seems to work. no name completions and other features.

I tried to look in the User and cpp configurations. everything is looked fine (all the auto-complete features are enabled)

What do I miss?

Update:
when I point to local folder (I had to install again the C/C++ extension this time for the "local" side) IntelliSense works perfectly. when switch again to remote host IntelliSense still does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Remote SSH has multiple "bugs" and some of them are mentioned in this post: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5044
check if You have similar issues. This could be IntelliSense + VS Code bug.

Comment: Thanks. I have not found it there. I guess I will add mine to the many others..